# Regular expression to get string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.x

---

i'm creating a script that parse log files... here's an example of the lines:

```
data = "09:55:04.125 mta         Messages       I Doc O:SERVER (NVS:SMTP/me@domain.com) R:NVS:FAXG3.I0.0101 mid:6393"
data2= "09:55:05.045 mta         Messages       I Doc O:SERVER (NVS:SMTP/me@domain.com) R:ADMIN (NVS:SMTP.0/me@domain.fr) mid:6397"
```

---

at first i have matched what's between the slash and two points but i've noticed that there's some lines like the first where the type "FAXG3.I0.0101" isn't followed by a slash

---

here's the regex i use:

```
exp = result = re.findall(r'[\w\.]+(?=:*)',data) # type S & D
```

---

the result i want is 'SMTP','FAXG3.I0.0101' for the first line and 'SMTP','SMTP.0' for the second. 
can someone help correcting my regex to get that ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is "NVS:" guaranteed to be in front of your matches? If so, you can just use `NVS:([\w\.]+)`:

```
re.findall(r'NVS:([\w\.]+)',data)
['SMTP', 'FAXG3.I0.0101']

re.findall(r'NVS:([\w\.]+)',data2)
['SMTP', 'SMTP.0']
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the trick

```
>>> for x in re.finditer('(NVS:([\w.]+?)(\s|/))', data2):
...     print x.groups()[1]
...
SMTP
SMTP.0
>>> for x in re.finditer('(NVS:([\w.]+?)(\s|/))', data):
...     print x.groups()[1]
...
SMTP
FAXG3.I0.0101
```